# Serializing a React component to Database

Tags: reactjs, serialization, components

Is that possible to serialize a React component, to store it into a database?

For instance, I've got a react component `Navbar` in a file named `Navbar.jsx`, rather than loading it from the file, I was wondering if it was possible to serialize it, so it can be stored in a Database or a cache, and then deserialized to my app?

Thanks !

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can do that with a Component. You can store the raw output HTML of the component, but you can't store any functions or logic. You could store just the name and use that to figure out what component to import at run time. How do you plan on using it?

Comment: What do you mean by _serialize it_ to a string? from where would you serialize it from? it must be in some kind of file first. in general you can, it's just a bunch of characters in the end. though i fail to see the benefit of this approach.

Comment: I'd like to be able to import new versions of components, or even new components when my app is live.

Comment: I think you would be better off with some type of continuous integration pipeline that redeploys your app on branch updates, like travis or circle. you could do this with a few bash scripts as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is bunch of characters and strings, A database can store strings.
Technically you can, is it a good approach? i doubt!
You got a huge echo system with hundreds of repositories types that can handle Sharing, Permissions, Versioning, build processing and what not.
I don't see any valid reason for storing it in a database.
But that's me.

Comment: it makes a lot of sense, and I was expecting it sounding like an awful approach. Storing the components in a Database (or a cache) will permit me to have a modular application, that can be updated "live", without having to be restarted to have the changes applied.

Comment: @dbrrt the "restarting" can all be done automatically and mostly transparently. pushing to master branch can trigger a deploy followed by a server event causing client pages to refresh themselves. pretty straightforward, much more so than keeping JS code in the database and having to eval it somehow

Comment: I agree with that, I'll investigate if that's feasible in our intranet

Comment: @azium got  good point. this exactly what i meant when i mentioned build processing in my answer.